# CentOS 7 issue - cannot install VMware Tools: There is insufficient disk space available in /usr/lib

Tags: centos, vmware

I cannot install VMware Tools on my CentOS 7 Minimal VM. I expanded out the VMDK another 4 GBs (started with 2 GBs) via vSphere, then [ran these commands](https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space) to try and use the new space on disk of the OS itself.

However, when I try to run the VMware Tools installer (`./vmware-install.pl`) it fails with this error:

```
There is insufficient disk space available in /usr/lib.  Please make at least
an additional 70740KB available.
Execution aborted.
```

I have the `vmware-tools-distrib` folder living in `~`

Here is the results of the `df -h /usr/lib` command:
    `[root@linux-a-08 /]# df -h /usr/lib`
    `Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`
    `/dev/mapper/centos-root  1.3G  1.3G   46M  97% /`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `df -h /usr/lib`

Comment: Assuming you did successfully extend the disk, try `resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root`.

Comment: Thanks. I got this: `[root@linux-a-08 /]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/centos-root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **Cloud-Utils-Growpart** was what I was after:
 https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/cloud-utils-growpart-0.29-2.el7.noarch.rpm.html